# Multiple elements which can be called via one element

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a set of Polymer 1.x components which act as fillable forms. Each form can be called via `<form-one></form-one>`, `<form-two></form-two>` etc...

```
<dom-module id="form-one">
  <template>
    form content
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
 Polymer({
  is: "form-one"
 });
</script>
```

I'm looking for a solution to combine them and to have only one element and call the forms like:
`<form-handler form="form-one"></form-handler>`

Where to start? And is it also possible to keep the dom modules in separated files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your element like this:

```
<dom-module id="form-handler">
  <template>
    <div id="formContainer">
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
 Polymer({
  is: "form-handler",
   properties:{
     form: {type:String, observer:'_formChanged'}
   },
   _formChanged: function(){
     var formElement = document.createElement(this.form);
     this.$.formContainer.empty();
     this.$.formContainer.append(formElement);
   }
 });
</script>
```